# php - encode json to path

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file and in it consists of site data. This site data is for a homepage (I decode the JSON into variables so I can echo them out within the HTML).

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  //start json stuff
  $path = "../assets/json/home.json";
  $fileexists = file_exists($path);
  if ($fileexists) {
    $json_d = file_get_contents($path,TRUE);
    $json = json_decode($json_d,TRUE);
  } else {
    die("Error retrieving site data - please refresh the page. If that doesn't work, please report a problem, here and come back later.");
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $navtitle = $_POST['navtitle'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];

    $json_arr = array('navtitle' => $navtitle, 'title' => $title);
    $json_enc = json_encode($json_arr);
    $json_result = file_put_contents($path, $json_enc);

    if($json_result) {
      echo "<script>alert('WORKING!');</script>";
    } else {
      echo "<script>alert('NO WORKING!');</script>";
    }
  }
?>
```

So, I have created the array, encoded the array and placed it in the file (I think) but I do not see any changes.

**NOTE:** I have added the `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">` meta tag to force the website/browser to grab the `home.json` file everytime the page is loaded in.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you see the alert?

Comment: @Barmar: I do, yes. I get the `WORKING` alert, so I assume the `$json_result` variable **always** equals `true` - otherwise it'd show the other. *I think.*

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you were getting one of the alerts, which implies that the code that tries to write to the file is running. But in that case, I can't think of a reason why the file isn't changing.

Comment: How are you determining whether the file is changing? Are you using the output of this script, or printing the file by hand?

Comment: If you're showing the contents of `$json`, that's the contents of the file **before** you changed it. You should put the code that reads the file **after** the code that changes the file.

Comment: @Barmar: I have a `<form>` and inside the form, I have an `<input>` with a `name="navtitle"`, hence in the PHP script `navtitle`... The user inputs something in the box and clicks the submit button. I want the contents of the input box to get put into the variable, to be then encoded in the JSON file - so when it is loaded up again, the user can see the changes.

Comment: The script appears to be doing that correctly. What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: @Barmar: I think the problem is occurring at the `file_put_contents` part. Just gotta' feelin' that I haven't used the correct function for putting encoded JSON data into a JSON file.

Comment: It looks fine to me. There's nothing special about encoded JSON, it's just a plain string.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes. I guess I'll have to turn on error messages to see if there is an error with anything. When I decode the file, the file is opened and read. Do I need to close it to open it again to write to it? If that makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111900/discussion-between-josh-murray-and-barmar).